# 3D object on 2D pattern - how to adjust?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I want to re-create this pattern (apart from arrows which play only role of direction indicators; black line is a Sin/Cos function):

[image]

I came up (for now) with this solution (code below). How to adjust the code so the kinks of those tubes are points on the Sin/Cos function?

```
helix[a_, b_][t_] := {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t], b*t}
listept1 = Table[helix[.45, 0.45][t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, \[Pi]/4}];
listept2 = Table[helix[0.25, 0.35][t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, .61}];
mapdecalgarde = Map[{0, 0, .25} + # &, {listept1}, {2}];
exterieurSup1 = Map[{0, 0, .25} + # &, listept1];
mapdecalgarde1 = Map[{0, 0, .5} + # &, listept1];
Listedepointgardecorps1 = 
  Flatten[{{mapdecalgarde1}, {exterieurSup1}}, 1];
ptsGarCor1 = Transpose[Listedepointgardecorps1];
    carat[{{x_, y_, z1_}, {x_, y_, z2_}}] := 
      Translate[
        Rotate[
          Translate[
            Tube[
              {{x, y, z1}, {x + (z2 - z1)/3, y, (z1 + z2)/2}, {x, y, z2}}, 
              (z2 - z1)/10], 
            {-x, -y, 0}], 
           2 π, {0, 0, 1}], 
        {x, 0, 0}]
    tube = 
      Graphics3D[{
        Opacity[0.2], Yellow, EdgeForm[Opacity[.2]], 
        Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 Pi}}, 0.6]}];
    Ntb = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0, 3, 0], carat /@ ptsGarCor1}];
    Show[{tube, Ntb}, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can modify the Frenet classic formulas to suit you:

```
r[a_, b_][t_] := {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t], b*t}
uT[a_, b_][t_] := Normalize[r[a, b]'[t1]] /. t1 -> t
vN[a_, b_][t_] := Normalize[uT[a, b]'[t1]] /. t1 -> t
vB[a_, b_][t_] := Normalize[Cross[r[a, b]'[t1], r[a, b]''[t1]]] /. t1 -> t

a = 1; b = 1;
Manipulate[Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{r[a, b][t]}, {t, -Pi/a, Pi/a}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 3}}],
  Graphics3D[{
    {Thick, Darker@Green, 
     Tube[{r[a, b][s], r[a, b][s] + uT[a, b][s]}, .1]}, {Thick, 
     Darker@Red, 
     Tube[{r[a, b][s], r[a, b][s] + vB[a, b][s]}, .1]}, {Thick, 
     Darker@Cyan, 
     Tube[{r[a, b][s], r[a, b][s] + vN[a, b][s]}, .1]}}]], {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not the thing I am looking for. I am not sure if it is visible on sketch but this 3D "boomerang" is in plane of a Sin/Cos function. The position of the kink is defined by the values of Sin/Cos function. In general shape of the "boomerang" maintains constant.